# ¿Cómo eliminar caracteres de una cadena usando PLSQL?

Tags: plsql, apex

Estoy almacenado un archivo en una tabla temporal.

```
 Declare 
    l_nombre_archivo = varchar2(300);    
    
   Begin

          select filename
             INTO   l_nombre_archivo
          FROM apex_application_temp_files              
          where name = :P200_FILE; ---Es el file browser

          :P200_FILENAME := l_nombre_archivo;  ---:P200_FILENAME es el label

   End;
```

Luego imprimo el filename en un label y me queda de la siguiente manera:
**miarchivo.txt**

¿Cómo puedo eliminar los caracteres .txt?

Resultado esperado imprimir solo:
**miarchivo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar las funciones [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSTR.html) Y [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html), por ejemplo:

```
select substr(filename,1,instr(filename,'.')-1)
             INTO   l_nombre_archivo
          FROM apex_application_temp_files              
          where name = :P200_FILE;
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio.